# How to process Excel file stored in S3 in AWS Lambda using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to iterate through each record in an excel file stored in a S3 bucket. How can I do this in a Java Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

To interact with an Excel Spreadsheet from an AWS Lambda function, you can use the [Interface WritableSheet](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/current/docs/jxl/write/WritableSheet.html) API. You can build Java logic to meet your business requirements. In fact, there is an example of using this API from within a Lambda function.

In this example, the Excel doc is retrieved from an Amazon S3 bucket, the data read from the Excel doc using the **WritableSheet** API, and the data is stored in an Amazon DynamoDB table.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/Creating_etl_workflow